# Sharing data between AppDomain using GAC (System.InvalidCastException)

Tags: c#, gac

I have created a 'StrongNamed' dll and installed it to the GAC successfully.

The app runs and shares data correctly; however, when I am in debug mode within Visual Studio, I get the following `InvalidCastException`.

Why won't it debug correctly?

Instead I'm getting the below error message : (code based on http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2012/07/25/150301.aspx)

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: [A]AppDomainTests.CrossDomainData cannot be cast to [B]AppDomainTests.CrossDomainData. Type A originates from 'StrongNamedDomainGateDll, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=98f280cda3cbf035' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Source\WindbgAuto\bin\AnyCPU\Release\StrongNamedDomainGateDll.dll'. Type B originates from 'StrongNamedDomainGateDll, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=98f280cda3cbf035' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Source\WindbgAuto\bin\AnyCPU\Release\StrongNamedDomainGateDll.dll'.
   at AppDomainTests.DomainGate.DoSomething(Int32 gcCount, IntPtr objAddress) in C:\Source\WindbgAuto\Tests\AppDomainTests\DomainGate.cs:line 24
   at AppDomainTests.DomainGate.DoSomething(Int32 gcCount, IntPtr objAddress)
   at AppDomainTests.DomainGate.Send(DomainGate gate, Object o) in C:\Source\WindbgAuto\Tests\AppDomainTests\DomainGate.cs:line 50
   at AppDomainTests.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Source\WindbgAuto\Tests\AppDomainTests\Program.cs:line 41
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you did not disable the Visual Studio Hosting process in the Project Debug Settings. Visual Studio will host the code in the hosting process within an AppDomain with no assembly sharing.

Comment: Yes we all meet here ;-). Please do not try to use this in production code since it will not be supported by MS at all. If you rely on it you will run into trouble with e.g. .NET 4.6.  or later.

Comment: yeah this is dev work - personal project for data analysis :-). just want a process to cache data and be super quick at sharing data i.e 0.001ms (wcf was adding .30ms to a call between processes) has to be in another process as changing code all the time of how to analyse data. saved intpr pointer of shared object to db so can load from another proccess but that process now gets a 'read or write proteced memory error, so back to the drawing board at the moment - app domains are confusing!.